# Non generic ZCL frame parsing

Tags: node.js, parsing, npm, ecmascript-6, zigbee

I have to decrypt frame from ZCL (Zigbee Cluster Library) and to interpretate it. So I found on NPM the "zcl-packet" module, who seems to do it well.

But, i work with sensors who use the "ZCL syntax", but who create their own cluster, so i have things like 0x8002 or 0x8003, who are not defined by ZCl, so the module doesn"t work properly, and i'm not able to decrypt as well my packet.

Example of trame :

110a800200002b00000075

- Flag(+en) : 0x11 (don't know if this is generic to ZCL)
- CommandID : 0x0A
- ClusterID : 0x8002
- AttributeID : 0x0000
- AttributeType : 0x2b (Int32_type)
- Data : 0x00000075

So if i try to parse it using the module, i got error, because i doesn't found the clusterID (that's seems normal)

So do i have to redevelop all (data parsing, etc), or can i just find a way to deal with and create my own cluster_id and deal with this module depending on the command ID, like by inheritance ?